# getting error when calling the function using sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get the form values and insert that values in the db using sencha touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397130/how-to-get-the-form-values-and-insert-that-values-in-the-db-using-sencha-touch)

im new to sencha touch.I want to create a form and submit that form details in the database .for this one i write the following code.

```
Ext.define("Form.view.Main",{
extend: "Ext.form.Panel",

 requires:['Ext.Button',
            'Ext.Spacer',
            'Ext.field.Password'
 ],
config: {
  fullscreen: true,
   id:'form',
items: [
    {
        xtype:'fieldset',
       items:[

           {
               xtype: 'textfield',
               name : 'name',
               label: 'Name'
           },
           {
               xtype: 'emailfield',
               name : 'email',
               label: 'Email',
               placeHolder: 'Email address',
               useClearIcon: true
           },
           {
               xtype: 'passwordfield',
               name : 'password',
               label: 'Password',
               allowBlank:'false'
           }
       ]

},
     {
                centered:'true',
                xtype:'button',
                id:'submitBtn',
                text:'Submit',
                ui:'confirm',
                width:100,
               listeners: {
                    tap : function(thisTxt,eventObj){
                        var form = Ext.getCmp('form');
                        var values = thisTxt.getValues();
                        alert(values.name);
                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                            url:'http://localhost/sencha2011/form/insert.php',
                            params:values,

                            success : function(response){
                                var text = response.responseText;
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', text);
                            },
                            failure : function(response){
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Error','Error while submitting the form');
                                console.log(response.responseText);
                            }

                        });

                    }

                }
    }
]
}
});
```

when i try to execute this app ,executed(debug) successfully.when i open the application in the browser ,i have the error as " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getValues' of undefined  " in console window,and form only displayed .when i click the submit button nothing happens.can any one help to solve this one.
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you put `id` of your form at the wrong place, it should be placed outside of the `items` config

```
config: {
  fullscreen: true,
  id: 'form'
  items: [
  ...........
}
```

Secondly, your query is wrong, change this query:

```
var form = Ext.getCmp(form);
```

to this:

```
var form = Ext.getCmp('form');
```

Finally, since `getvalues` will return you an object containing the value of each field in the form so if you want to access, for instance, your `name` field, just do like this:

```
alert(values.name);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: user1479606, thanks for reply,i changed the code as u said above,but still im getting the same error message in console (Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getValues' ) and when i click the submit button nothing happens .

Comment: Are you sure you put form wrapped by the quote in your query?

Comment: user1479606, updated the code above,can you check once?

Comment: Your `id:form` should placed outside the `items` config. Read my answer careful please

Comment: yes,i changed the id ,to config .but same error is coming.when i click the submit button,nothing happens

Comment: alert message also not coming.in the above code ,  var values = thisTxt.getValues(); i think,values variable doesn't get the values from form

Comment: It should be `form.getValues` not `thisTxt.getValues()`

Comment: okay,i changed the values variable to form.getValues. but no change in the o/p.can i change anything in my code.

Comment: in console window,i got this error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getValues'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var values = thisTxt.getValues();
```

try

```
var values = form.getValues();
```

or

```
var values = this.parent.getValues();
```

because `thisTxt` is the [button](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Button-event-tap) not the form, and [getValues()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-getValues) should be called on form panel.

Comment: I tried both ,but no change .same error in the console.can i change the varible ,in tap function?

Comment: do `console.log(thisTxt)`, `console.log(form)`, `console.log(this.parent)`, `console.log(this.parent.parent)` and check your browser's console to see what these things are and which one has getValues() method. You may use JS debugger to run all such commands.

Comment: i placed the all console msg's as u said, in console window same error is coming    Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getValues'

Comment: function(thisTxt,eventObj) can i change the variable in this function