# how to get the form values and insert that values in the db using sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want to store the login form details in the database .for that,i wrote the following code .

In my view code

```
Ext.define('SampleForm.view.LoginForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    //id:'loginform',
    requires:[
            'Ext.field.Email',
            'Ext.field.Password'
    ],
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        layout:{
            type:'vbox'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Login',
        id: 'loginform',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype:'textfield',
                        label:'Name',
                        name:'name'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'emailfield',
                        name: 'email',
                        label: 'Email'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                        name: 'password',
                        label: 'Password'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                width: '30%',
                text: 'Login',
                ui: 'confirm',
        action:'btnSubmitLogin'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

In controller

```
Ext.define("SampleForm.controller.LoginForm", {
    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",

    config: {
        view: 'SampleForm.view.LoginForm',
        refs: [
        {
            loginForm: '#loginform',
            Selector: '#loginform'
        }
        ],
        control: {
            'button[action=btnSubmitLogin]': {
                tap: "onSubmitLogin"
            }
        }
    },
    onSubmitLogin: function () {

    alert('Form Submitted successfully');
    console.log("test");
    var values = this.getloginform();
    /* Ext.Ajax.request({
                      url: 'http://www.servername.com/login.php',
                      params: values,

                      success: function(response){
                          var text = response.responseText;
                          Ext.Msg.alert('Success', text);
                     }

                     failure : function(response) {
                           Ext.Msg.alert('Error','Error while submitting the form');
                           console.log(response.responseText);
                     }
              });*/
     form.submit({
           url:"http://localhost/sencha2011/form/login.php"
     });
    },
    launch: function () {
        this.callParent();
        console.log("LoginForm launch");
    },
    init: function () {
        this.callParent();
        console.log("LoginForm init");
    }
});
```

when i click the submit button,alert message coming,but values aren't stored in the database.and in console im getting this error,Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getloginform'.

Can anyone help me to how to insert the values in  the db.

Comment: You better improve your previous post then ask for a duplicate question. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372967/getting-error-when-calling-the-function-using-sencha-touch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372967/getting-error-when-calling-the-function-using-sencha-touch)

Comment: user1479606, thanks for your suggestion,actually i tried that solutions,what you said ,but i'm failed to get the o/p.that's why i tried in anotherway.this time i succeded to get the messages in the alert box and consle window .but values aren't getting from the form.that's why i placed my question again.I hope some one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is **case-sensitive**. From [Sencha Touch docs:](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/controllers)

> These getter functions are generated based on the refs you define and
>   always follow the same format - 'get' followed by the capitalized ref
>   name.

To use the getter method for ref, `loginForm`, and to get the form values use:

```
var values = this.getLoginForm().getValues();
```

Comment: Josh , i changed var values = this.getLoginForm().getValues(); to this , now i'm getting the error in console as object has no method getLoginForm

Comment: @lucky Hm, perhaps there is an underlying issue. Are you getting any other errors?

Comment: no,this error only coming in the console. i want to insert these values into login table(in database)

Comment: @lucky Did you figure it out?

Comment: yes,now i'm getting the values in the values variable, but those values aren't inserted in the table.i placed the console.log statement and i'm getting the values in the console.now i want to insert these values in the db table  through a php page ,where the connections are given .i used post method in the controller

Comment: Ext.Ajax.request({
                            url: 'http://localhost/sencha2011/form/insert.php',
       params: valuesUser,
                            method: 'POST',

                            success: function(response){
                                var text = response.responseText;
                                console.log(valuesUser);
                                //Ext.Msg.alert('Success', text);

                            },

Comment: you have any idea ,how to send these values to php file

Comment: @lucky How did you fix the first problem? As for your new problem, I suggest opening a new question with the relevant code and description. :) I can help you there!

Comment: I have made some modifications in my code ,which solves my problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23030/discussion-between-lucky-and-josh)